# How to verify GPG signatures (.asc files) with .NET Framework System.Security.Cryptography routines

Tags: .net, cryptography, digital-signature, gnupg

How can I verify the signature of a file that was signed by gpg?

I have: the exported public key that signed it, the file, and the .asc file with the signature in it.

This routine seems to be the guts of what I need, now it's basically a problem of format conversion: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.dsa.verifysignature.aspx

Actually calling gpg is out as (1) I don't want to ship it and (2) I don't want to mess with the user's keyring if they already have it installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Format conversion" is merely writing part of OpenPGP code - take RFC 4880 and start writing. An alternative is to take an existing implementation of OpenPGP standard for .NET, such as our [OpenPGPBlackbox](http://www.eldos.com/sbb/net-pgp.php) or BouncyCastle.

Comment: About 300 lines of C# code was able to do the format conversion for this case. Thanks for the references.